# MySQL Select JOIN 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three basic tables:

```
tblUsers:

    usrID     usrFirst     usrLast
      1        John          Smith
      2        Bill          Jones
      3        Jane          Johnson

pm_data:

id     date_sent              title          sender_id  thread_id         content
2   2009-07-29 18:46:13     Subject 1           1         111        Message 2!
3   2009-07-29 18:47:21     Another Subject     1         222        Message 3!

pm_info:

id  thread_id   receiver_id  is_read
1     111           2            0
2     111           3            0
3     222           2            0
4     222           3            0
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is create an inbox.

So, if usrID 2 (Bill Jones) opens his inbox, he will see that he 2 unread (hence the 'is_read' column) messages (threads #111 and #222).

Basically, I need to know how to set up my SELECT statement to JOIN all three tables (the relationship between pm_data and pm_info brings about the message info, while the relationship between tblUsers and pm_data brings about the 'display name' of the sender), to show the most recent (by timestamp?) thread on top.

Thus, we would see something like this:

```
<?php  $usrID = 2;  ?>

<table id="messages">
  <tr id="id-2">
  <td>
   <span>
     From: John Smith
    </span>
    <span>2009-07-29 18:47:21</span>
  </td>
 <td>
 <div>Another subject</div>
 </td></tr>
<tr id="id-1">
 <td>
   <span>
     From: John Smith
   </span>
   <span>2009-07-29 18:46:13</span>
</td>
 <td>
   <div>Subject 1</div>
 </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Hopefully this makes sense!  Thanks for any help!

EDIT:  Here's my final answer:

I took lc's advice, and made the relationship between the two tables based on id (added a column called 'message_id' to pm_info).

Then, tweaked the MySQL statement around a little bit to come up with this:

```
SELECT pm_info.is_read, sender.usrFirst as sender_name,
pm_data.date_sent, pm_data.title, pm_data.thread_id
FROM pm_info
INNER JOIN pm_data ON pm_info.message_id = pm_data.id
INNER JOIN tblUsers AS sender ON pm_data.sender_id = sender.usrID
WHERE pm_data.date_sent IN(SELECT MAX(date_sent) FROM pm_data WHERE pm_info.message_id = pm_data.id GROUP BY thread_id) AND pm_info.receiver_id = '$usrID' ORDER BY date_sent DESC
```

This seems to work for me (so far).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need two joins. Something like the following should get you started (although I don't 100% understand the relationship between `pm_data` and `pm_info`):

```
SELECT pm_info.is_read, sender.usrFirst + ' ' + sender.usrLast as sender_name, 
    pm_data.date_sent, pm_data.title, pm_data.thread_id
FROM pm_info
INNER JOIN pm_data ON pm_info.thread_id = pm_data.thread_id
INNER JOIN tblUsers AS sender ON pm_data.sender_id = tblUsers.usrID
WHERE pm_info.receiver_id = @USER_ID /*in this case, 2*/
ORDER BY pm_data.date_sent DESC
```

I'm assuming the relation between `pm_data` and `pm_info` is the thread id. If it isn't, you should be able to adjust the above to whatever you need. I've also sorted by date sent here, but **it won't keep the threads together**. I'm not sure if you want to keep them together or not from the way you've phrased your question.

---

**If you want to keep threads together**, you'll need a more complicated query:

```
SELECT pm_info.is_read, sender.usrFirst + ' ' + sender.usrLast as sender_name, 
    pm_data.date_sent, pm_data.title, pm_data.thread_id
FROM pm_info
INNER JOIN pm_data ON pm_info.thread_id = pm_data.thread_id
INNER JOIN tblUsers AS sender ON pm_data.sender_id = tblUsers.usrID
INNER JOIN (SELECT thread_id, MAX(date_sent) AS max_date
            FROM pm_data
            GROUP BY thread_id) AS most_recent_date 
           ON pm_data.thread_id = most_recent_date.thread_id
WHERE pm_info.receiver_id = @USER_ID /*in this case, 2*/
ORDER BY most_recent_date.max_date DESC, pm_data.thread_id, 
    pm_data.date_sent DESC
```

This query uses a subselect to find the most recent modified date for each thread, then sorts by this first.

Comment: Thanks lc, for your reply.  Your complicated query is definitely the direction I'm heading.  It's not throwing any errors, but it's doing a couple things: 1) It still shows all parts of the thread (even the user's sent items relating to the thread) and 2)It's showing it in duplicates.  Let me know if you need me to be more explicit.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dodinas 1)It will show all parts of the thread. If you don't want to show everything, you'll have to think of what exactly you want to filter out and add it to the WHERE clause. There might also be more in the relationship between `pm_data` and `pm_info` that I'm missing, because all I have to go on right now is the thread ID... 2)Can you post a little more of the tables' contents so I can see where this might be going wrong? INNER JOINs shouldn't be producing any rows in duplicate. It's also possibly your error is in the PHP after executing the query...

Comment: @lc: Thanks for the reply.  Basically, I don't think the issue's with the PHP.  However, it could be an issue with the way my db is structured.  Basically, what I posted is the tables I'm working with.  The 'thread_id' is the only thing that's relating the two tables.  Perhaps I need to make a change to my db structure?

Comment: Well, one quick change I would make is to add the message id to the ‘pm_info‘ table and join on that instead. That way you know which messages are intended for whom, not just which users have received a message for which thread. This is more in-line with what you want for a messaging system. The two tables are a good idea tho because you can do multiple recipients easily without having to copy the message body multiple times. As for the duplicates, are you sure you don't have multiple copies of the same record or something?

Comment: Thanks lc.  Your suggestion helped with changing the relationship between the tables.  I tweaked the SELECT statement a bit, (see my edit in original post above), and it appears to be working fine.  That is, until I find another leak of some sort.  But hopefully I won't!  :-)   Thanks for helping me understand the JOIN statement-- it's not until I have problems with it that I really have to sit down and figure out how it actually works.

Answer (score 4):

To get the list of messages for a user along with who and when they sent it, you can use the following query:

```
select
    s.usrFirst + ' ' + s.usrLast as SenderName,
    m.Title,
    m.DateSent,
    i.IsRead
from
    tblUsers r
    inner join pm_info i on
        r.receiver_id = i.receiver_id
    inner join pm_data m on
        i.thread_id = m.thread_id
    inner join tblUsers s on
        m.sender_id = s.userID
where
    r.usrid = @id
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you *can* join a table to itself (here, `tblUsers` shows up twice: Once for the recipient, and again for the sender).

If you'd like to see only unread messages, you can put `and i.IsRead = 0` in the `where` clause.