# PHP/MYSQL Join multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Fields from table **TICKETS**:

```
ID TICKETID CUSTOMER
234   29      9798797
235   76      7887878
```

Fields from table **RECEPTS**:

```
ID   DATENEW    TOTAL
234 2012-12-03   22.57
235 2012-12-03   33.98
```

Fields from table **PAYMENTS**:

```
RECEIPT   PAYMENT
234       cash
235       debt
```

Fields from table **CUSTOMERS**:

```
ID            NAME
9798797       John
7887878       Helen
```

The relation between tables is very easy to understand: `TICKETS.CUSTOMER=CUSTOMERS.ID;` `PAYMENTS.RECEIPT=RECEIPTS.ID=TICKETS.ID`

The Final Result I would like to achive to have:

```
TICKETID DATENEW      NAME    PAYMENT TOTAL
29       2012-12-03   John     cash   22.57
76       2012-12-03   Helen    debt   33.98
```

I tried to do something like this but it wrong somewhere:

```
Select TICKETS.TICKETID, RECEIPTS.DATENEW, PAYMENTS.TOTAL,  CUSTOMERS.NAME, PAYMENTS.PAYMENT FROM PEOPLE, RECEIPTS 
INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
ORDER BY RECEIPTS.DATENEW
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204217/mysql-select-join-3-tables

Comment: what's wrong? is there an error?

Comment: Why you are reference the table `People` in the from clause where you are not selecting anything from it, nor you sepecified the join condition of it with the other tables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to get the result:

```
select t.ticketid,
  date_format(r.datenew, '%Y-%m-%d') datenew,
  c.name,
  p.payment,
  r.total
from tickets t
left join RECEPTS r
  on t.id = r.id
left join CUSTOMERS c
  on t.customer = c.id
left join payments p 
  on t.id = p.RECEIPT
  and r.id = p.RECEIPT
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c27e9/5)

Result:

```
| TICKETID |    DATENEW |  NAME | PAYMENT | TOTAL |
---------------------------------------------------
|       29 | 2012-12-03 |  John |    cash | 22.57 |
|       76 | 2012-12-03 | Helen |    debt | 33.98 |
```

Comment: Thank you! your way was first and I modified some small mistakes there like p.total instead of r.total by myself. I am surprised your code is working in Demo :)

Answer (score 5):

This will give the output that you want:

```
SELECT
    p.RECEIPT AS TICKETID,
    r.DATENEW,
    c.NAME,
    p.PAYMENT,
    r.TOTAL
FROM
    PAYMENTS p
LEFT JOIN
    RECEIPTS r ON r.ID = p.RECEIPT
LEFT JOIN
    TICKETS t ON t.ID = p.RECEIPT
LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMERS c ON c.ID = t.CUSTOMER
ORDER BY
    r.DATENEW DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you code! It is a good one as well, sorry but I do not know how to choose two answers :) Really appreciate your effort!